# why does flask logs only when app.debug = True?

Tags: python, flask

in main :

```
handler = RotatingFileHandler('/tmp/mylog')
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
app.logger.addHandler(handler)
my_glob.logger = app.logger
app.debug = True
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

in a 'url' :

```
import my_glob
...
handling get request here:
  logger = my_glob.logger
  logger.info('this wont show unless app.debug=True is specified')
  logger.error('this always shows up')
```

if I do this, it works. If I remove app.debug = True, it doesn't work. But flask documentation says that app.debug is on local environments/debugging, not on production. So what should I use to enable logging on info/debug levels ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because flask considers `ERROR` as the default logging level if you do not set up log level, see: https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/master/flask/logging.py#L28.

The solution is to add `app.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)` before usage.

Comment: But if INFO is the default, why does `logger.info(...)` doesn't show up ?

Comment: Just had the same issue, works perfectly. @Thomas Could you accept this answer?